# How to expand a binary NB classifier to a multilabel one SKlearn?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

I have trained a Nb classifier using sklearn but now it returns only 1 and -1. Is there any possibility to make it return pos, neg or neutral ?
This is my code :

```
p = Pipeline([
    ("vectorizer", CountVectorizer()),
    ("selector", SelectPercentile(percentile=20)),
    ("nb", MultinomialNB())
])

p.fit(X, y)
joblib.dump(p, 'skclassif.pkl', compress = 1)
print(p.predict(["I hate this car"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

It will return classes that you train it on - thus if you want three classes pass three classes in `y`, that's all.

Comment: My training data contains only neg and pos but I was thinking it can be a workaround such as using the probability of a string to be pos or neg For example in nltk I found something like this : `class_prob = self.sentiment_classifier.prob_classify(features).prob(class_label)
    return class_label if class_prob > 0.6 else 'neutral'`

Comment: you can hard code your own rules, but this is rarely a good idea, human "intuition" is rather a bad statistics :-) so - if you want such behavior - wrap NB in your own class and write your own predict on top of predict_proba from NB.